# AndEngine getting error: Supplied pTextureAtlasSource must not exceed bounds of Texture

Tags: android, andengine

im new to android gaming and started andengine and facing problem while using createTiledFromAsset 
the code where im getting problem is

```
@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(128, 128,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
                    "move.png", 0, 0, 10, 1);
    mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlas);

}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    mMainScene = new Scene();
    mMainScene
            .setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    player = new AnimatedSprite(0, 0, mPlayerTextureRegion);

    mMainScene.attachChild(player);
    return mMainScene;
}
```

im not getting the error as my BitmapTextureAtlas is of 128*128 and each tiled part coming from createTiledFromAsset should be of 78*85 as the passed arguments to it are 1 row and 10 columns and my source image is of 779*85 which means when the width is tiled to 10 parts then 779/10=78 approx which will be width of each tiled part and as row is 1 so 85/1=85 hence the width*height of each tiled part which is to be placed on the BitmapTextureAtlas is 78*85 and the BitmapTextureAtlas itself has size 128*128 then why the error saying `Supplied pTextureAtlasSource must not exceed bounds of Texture`
what is happening here ...? or im not understanding the actual functions ...? if im wrong then how the process of createTiledFromAsset is working........?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand BitmapTextureAtlas correctly, you are trying to put 779*85 image into the small space of 128*128. TextureAtlas is a large canvas on which you are supposed to place many images. These images are later accessed using object called TextureRegion, which basically specifies the size and coordinates of the smaller picture on the canvas. The method createTiledFromAsset probably copies the original image 1:1 onto the TextureAtlas and saves the coordinates of the tiles.

Please note that TextureRegion has nothing to do with the image itself, it is merely a "pointer" to the place on TextureAtlas where the image is stored.

To get the idea of what a TextureAtlas actually is, look at the awesome pictures at the bottom of this page:
http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html

Answer (score 5):

I found the same problem too. I am using a large sprite sheet, and try to use it. after searching, I found some clue in this tutorial: [getting-started-working-with-images](http://andengineguides.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/getting-started-working-with-images/) and i realize that the value of width and height used in:

`BitmapTextureAtlas(WIDTH, HEIGHT ,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);`

must be higher than the image size. for example if I use 1200*100 sprite sheet, I must use the width and height higher than 1200*100.

`BitmapTextureAtlas(2047, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);`